# Group nearby dates together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of variable dates that I would like to group together, preferably in javascript.

ie.

```
2014-08-12
2014-08-10
2014-07-28
2014-07-27
2014-01-27
2013-04-27
2003-02-12
```

This list of days can be completely dynamic, but here is an example resultset.

Can anyone think of an elegant way to group dates that are considered to be 'near' each other together, which in this case would be:

```
2014-08-12
2014-08-10
2014-07-28
2014-07-27

2014-01-27

2013-04-27

2003-02-12
```

Comment: _"...  preferably in javascript."_ Why using the tag `python` then? Please fix either your question or the tags.

Comment: I think all dates are near each other, give or take a couple thousand years. Here's my code: `function group(dates) { return dates; }`.

Comment: What did you try so far? If nothing then start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: How do you define "near"? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is:

1. Convert all date strings to numbers using `.getTime()`
2. Sort
3. Group
4. Convert back to date string

An example of this:

```
var dates = ['2014-08-12', '2014-08-10', '2014-07-28', '2014-07-27', '2014-01-27', '2013-04-27', '2003-02-12'],
    groups = [],
    last = 0

dates.map(function (each) {
    return new Date(each).getTime() // 1.
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    return b-a // 2.
}).forEach(function (each) {
    if (Math.abs(each-last) > 1e10) { // 1e10 ms = 116 days
        groups.push([]) // 3.
    }
    groups[groups.length-1].push(each)
    last = each
})

groups.map(function (dates) {
    return dates.map(function (each) {
        return new Date(each).toISOString().substr(0, 10) // 4.
    }).join('\n')
}).join('\n\n')
```

You can adjust the `1e10` value to whatever `nearby dates` means to your application